# Linking between templates

Tags: ember.js

I don't understand templates and routes.

My code:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  Hello
   <nav>
    {{#link-to 'index'}}Index{{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'contact'}}Contact{{/link-to}}
   </nav>
   </script>
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
   about
   </script>
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact">
   favorites
   </script>
```

and router.js:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("index", { path: "/" });
    this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
    this.route("contact", { path: "/contact" });
});
```

What is wrong? Output is blank page. There appeared a problem when I had inserted {{#link-to}} code.
I did that by an emberjs [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/).

Comment: look at browser's javascript console for errors. possible you are using old ember version where `link-to` not exist

Comment: Ember version is: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a place where your templates you are linking to should display, such a placeholder is called an `outlet`, so simply add `{{outlet}}` where in you `application` template you want your routes corresponding templates to be rendered into:

Also note, the [`linkTo`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_linkTo) helper is called `linkTo` and not `link-to` depending on the ember release you are using:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  Hello
  <nav>
   {{#linkTo 'index'}}Index{{/linkTo}}
   {{#linkTo 'about'}}About{{/linkTo}}
   {{#linkTo 'contact'}}Contact{{/linkTo}}
 </nav>
 {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
  about
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact">
  favorites
</script>
```

Working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/UhEyAJe/4/edit).

Hope it helps.